# No way to do ECDH with OpenSSL from the command line?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, openssl

I've scoured this website and the OpenSSL wiki pages, and done numerous internet searches, and I've come to the seemingly incredible conclusion that one cannot generate an ECDH shared secret key using a given public key and a given private key from the openssl command line. There is at least one other post on this web site that claims you can, without providing an example.

I know the wiki does provide 'C' code examples, but my use case is such that having the command line capability would've been much preferred.

If anyone can kindly disabuse me of this notion by providing an example, I would surely appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do roughly what you described:

```
openssl genpkey -out alice.pem -algorithm EC \
  -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 \
  -pkeyopt ec_param_enc:named_curve
openssl pkey -pubout -in alice.pem -out alice.pub
openssl genpkey -out bob.pem -algorithm EC \
  -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 \
  -pkeyopt ec_param_enc:named_curve
openssl pkey -pubout -in bob.pem -out bob.pub
openssl pkeyutl -derive -out alicebob.key -inkey alice.pem -peerkey bob.pub
openssl pkeyutl -derive -out bobalice.key -inkey bob.pem -peerkey alice.pub
cmp alicebob.key bobalice.key
```

But, who knows whether this implements a secure DH system?  You should really consider using X25519, *e.g.* via NaCl crypto_box, rather than stringing together generic OpenSSL incantations like this.

Comment: "pkeyutl -derive"!!! That's what I was looking for. How come nobody ever posted this anywhere, least of all in the wiki pages? Because no one had a use case until now?

Trust me, my use case does not involve implementing a secure DH system.

Comment: So the output format of the key does not appear to be DER, or PEM, or ASN1? It looks to be raw hex. And as usual, the man page is silent on this point.

Can I also assume then that the shared secret key is the X coordinate of the calculated curve point?

Comment: @Phil It's the output of whatever `EVP_PKEY_derive` computes.  Good luck chasing the chain of abstracted indirections down the rabbit hole of OpenSSL guts to find out what this really is!

Comment: No kidding. I got to this point after some hours and hit a brick wall: inside openssl/crypto/evp/exchange.c, line #72: `exchange->derive = OSSL_get_OP_keyexch_derive(fns);`

This is supposedly the function that does the heavy lifting? Except, guess what: It's not defined ANYWHERE that google can find. I didn't just search the git repo, I searched the internet and couldn't find this function. So WTH??
Pith poor documentation just seriously chaps my hide.

Comment: @Phil It is defined here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/d8c98d79d1bb1dc3261d9b4fc2bc36074aec88f6/include/openssl/core_numbers.h#L397.  The macro `OSSL_CORE_MAKE_FUNC` concatenates `OSSL_get_` with `OP_keyexch_derive`.  The effect is to set `exchange->derive` to `(OSSL_OP_keyexch_derive_fn *)fns->function`.  That said, I think you might actually be looking for pkey_ec_kdf_derive in crypto/ec/ec_pmeth.c.

Comment: SMH!! A number of juicy four letter acronyms come to mind, but I will muzzle myself this time. Thanks! BTW I tried to put "@Squeamish" into my reply but it wouldn't take.

Comment: @Phil (Commenting on a post always pings the author of the post, so there is no need to tag them to get that effect.)

Comment: ...but I always see "@Phil" on your posts.

Comment: @Phil Correct—that way you get a notification, which wouldn't happen if I didn't, because you're not the author of the _answer_ that this is a comment on.

Comment: `pkey_ec_kdf_derive` was another rabbit hole. It calls `pkey_ec_derive` that calls `ECDH_compute_key` that calls `eckey->meth->compute_key`. `pc_ec_derive` sets eckey out of 1 of 2 contexts. So I had to wind my way all the way back up to the top to find out how these contexts and ultimately "compute_key" gets set.

Long story short, I had to wade through all the store_loader crap and get to the point where I was comfortable with the belief that the derive function is probably determined when the private key is read in from a file. It's probably `ecdh_simple_compute_key` inside ecdh_ossl.c.

Comment: The derive CLI command doesn't seem to be the raw Diffie-Hellman shared secret. I tested with X25519 keys and the bytes I get from OpenSSL derive don't match up with what I get from my Golang software ECDH, and Golang's stdlib's ECDH bytes line up with the test vectors in RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7748#section-6.1)