# How does this formula work $(aG + bG) = (a + b) G$ in ECDSA?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, keys, cryptocurrency

Please explain how does this formula $(aG + bG) = (a + b) G$ work in ECDSA?

[According to the source:](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2756/how-to-properly-add-ecdsa-private-keys?rq=1)

$a$ and $b$ are different private keys

Suppose

$a = 3$

$b = 4$

then the public key is $Q = aG$ and $W = bG$ (secp256k1)

```
Q = F9308A019258C31049344F85F89D5229B531C845836F99B08601F113BCE036F9

W = E493DBF1C10D80F3581E4904930B1404CC6C13900EE0758474FA94ABE8C4CD13
```

Now we take the formula $(a + b)G$

$(3 + 4)G$

$7g$

$c = 7$

public key $P = cG$

```
P = 5CBDF0646E5DB4EAA398F365F2EA7A0E3D419B7E0330E39CE92BDDEDCAC4F9BC
```

Now take the formula $(aG + bG)$

$(Q + W)$

And the amount of public keys $(Q + W)$ will be

```
DDC465F353664403A152988A8BA8662FC6EEFEEEE3076EF93B2A2732D56EC2CB
```

Why it turns out:

```
DDC465F353664403A152988A8BA8662FC6EEFEEEE3076EF93B2A2732D56EC2CB
```

Why is the answer of this sum not this value:

```
5CBDF0646E5DB4EAA398F365F2EA7A0E3D419B7E0330E39CE92BDDEDCAC4F9BC
```

Comment: $G$, $Q$, $W$ are elliptic curve points and have two coordinates each. How come you have a single integer? How are you computing $aG$ and so on?

Answer (score 1):

> ..how does this formula $(aG+bG) = (a+b)G$ work in ECDSA?

Perfectly well. It follows from the definition of $kG$ as $\overbrace{G+\cdots+G}^{k\text{ times}}$, associativity and commutativity of point addition. Notice that operator $+$ in $(aG+bG)$ and $G+\cdots+G$ is elliptic curve point addition, while operator $+$ in $(a+b)$ is addition in $\Bbb Z$ (signed integers) or $\Bbb Z_n$ (integers modulo $n$, where $n$ is the order of $G$).

Be confident that $3G+4G=7G$ holds, and if $Q=3G$, $W=4G$, $P=7G$ then $Q+W=P$.
***The issue is on what arguments the point addition of the final $+$ is computed.***

In the question, what's shown after `Q =` is the X coordinate $Q_x$ of point $Q$. The Y coordinate is missing. Therefore what follows `Q =` does not settle between two points: $Q$ of coordinates $(Q_x,Q_y)$ and $-Q$ of coordinates $(Q_x,Q'_y)$ with $(Q_y)^2=(Q_x)^3+7\bmod p$ (per the equation of [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#page=13)) and $Q'_y=p-Q_y$. Same issue for $W$ and $P$.

> Why is the answer of this sum not this value (..)

This value ended up being the X coordinate for $Q-W$ (or equivalently $-Q+W$) instead of $Q+W$ as thought, due to the above. This also is the X coordinate for the base point $G$, because $Q-W=3G-4G=(3-4)G=(-1)G=-G$.

Answer (score 0):

> How does this formula work (aG+bG)=(a+b)G in ECDSA?

This is due to the definition of scalar multiplication of Elliptic Curves.

$$[a]g = \overbrace{g+\cdots+g}^{{a\hbox{ - }times}}$$
$$[b]g = \overbrace{g+\cdots+g}^{{b\hbox{ - }times}}$$

then $$[a+b]g = \overbrace{g+\cdots+g}^{{a+b\hbox{ - }times}} = \overbrace{g+\cdots+g}^{{a\hbox{ - }times}} + \overbrace{g+\cdots+g}^{{b\hbox{ - }times}} = [a]g+[b]g$$

> Why is the answer of this sum not this value:

The addition on Elliptic Curves is different from integers and they have a [geometric meaning](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66296/18298).

[image: Geometric interpretation of addition on a Weierstrass curve]

We, however, arithmetically can define the addition rules in affine coordinates as;

Let $P=(x_1,x_2)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ be two point in the elliptic curve.

1. $P+O=O+P=P$
2. If $x_1 = x_2 $ and $y_1 = - y_2$ and $Q =(x_2,y_2)=(x_1,−y_1)=−P$ then $P + (-P) = O$
3. If $Q \neq -P$ then the addition $P+Q = (x_3,y_3)$ and the coordinate can be calculated by;

\begin{align}
x_3 = & \lambda^2 -x_1 - x_2  \mod p\\
y_3 = & \lambda(x_1-x_3) -y_1 \mod p
\end{align}

$$
\lambda =
\begin{cases}
\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1},  & \text{if $P \neq Q$} \\[2ex]
\frac{3 x_1^2+a}{2y_1},  & \text{if $P = Q$} \\[2ex]
\end{cases}$$

So, $[3]P$ can be calculated as $([2]P)+P$, one doubling, and one addition. This is actually a hint for the **double and add algorithm**. Below is a simple Python function to show this and this is the addition version of the repeated-squaring method.

```
def double_and_add(n, x):

    result = 0
    double = x

    for bit in bits(n):
        if bit == 1:
            result += double
        double *= 2

    return result
```

---

<sub>Note that this addition and doubling rules are generic. According to curve and used coordinates faster versions are available.</sub>

Comment: Please give a detailed answer on an example of how scalar multiplication of elliptic curves occurs, for example, for a = 3? with parameters secp256k1
g = Point (79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,
           483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8,
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141)

Comment: @Rozwrcd Please see the update.