# Elliptic curve commitments mod p

Tags: elliptic-curves

As far as I understand secp256k1 is defined over the group p with

`p = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F`

I don't really understand how out of bounds values are handled in particular with homomorphism of the commitments.
Assume I commit to the value `5` which would be $G + G + G + G + G$ and then commit to the value `p + 5` which would be $(p+5)G$ will those be the same commitment?

Based on this assumption I have implemented the following javascript code (using [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic) library ):

```
it('Test mult property of commitments', () => {
    const T1 = ec.g.mul(secp256k1.p + 5n);
    const T2 = ec.g.mul(Maths.mod(secp256k1.p + 5n, secp256k1.p));
    const T3 = ec.g.mul(5n);
    assert(T1.eq(T2));
    assert(T2.eq(T3));
});
```

In this example, `T2` and `T3` are the same, but `T1` is different, so it seems like my assumption is incorrect, does this mean I can commit to values greater than p?

Comment: ECC Point addition is not an [integer addition](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75603/18298).

Comment: But it's additive homomorphic, so a C(5) + C(5) = C(10) and my problem is in understanding what happens to this homomorphism when dealing with values bigger than p.

Comment: In EC, we write as $[5]P = P+P+P+P+P$ where $P$ is a point on the curve and addition is performed according to group law. If I've understood correctly, you are adding integers. Could you write your equations in terms of this notation?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my original post. Maybe you can take another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf),  Koblitz curve secp256k1 defined by $T = (p, a, b, G, n, h)$

- **$p$** defines the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$,

  $p=2^{256} − 2^{32} − 2^{9} − 2^8 − 2^7 − 2^6 − 2^4 − 1$ or in hex

  `FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F`
- The curve $E: y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$  is defined by:
- **a** = `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`
- **b** = `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000007`
- **Base point** $G$ in compressed for `0279BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798`

  and in uncompressed form `04079BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8`
- **The order** $n$ of $G$, i.e. $[n]G = \mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is point at infinity, or the identity element in additive elliptic curve group.

  `FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C`
- with co-factor **h** is `01`

When you add an element according to the group law, if one of the coordinates exceeds the $p$ take mod $p$.

For the scalar, you can use $\mod n$

$$[x]G = [x \bmod n]G$$ In your case, we can see it in this way, too.

$$[n+5]G = [5]G + [n]G = [5]G + \mathcal{O} = [5]G $$

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the prime $p$ over which the curve is defined (the coordinate of the points are all defined mod $p$) with the prime $q$ which is the curve cardinality and is also prime.

We have $qG = G + \ldots + G = \infty$ the neutral element (like $0$ with the addition with numbers).

Taking your example, you have: $T_1 = (p+5)G$ and $T_2 = 5G$. Of course it is not the same since $p + 5 \not\equiv 5 \bmod q$.

You will find the value $q$ somewhere in the parameters of the curve and if you replace $p$ with $q$, the equality will hold.