# What is the symbolic solution?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let in ECDSA, $G$ is the base point, $P$ is a public key with the corresponding private key $k$. $G_2$ is another base point, $k_2$ is another private key. $P$ and all variables except $k$ are known.

Consider the following system of equations:

$\begin{align}[k]\,G &= P\\
[k_2]\,G_2 &= P\end{align}$

Givens:

- $G = (G_x,G_y)$ (Constant)
- $P = (P_x,P_y)$
- $k_2 = 11$
- $G_2 =({G_2}_x,{G_2}_y)$

Question: what is the symbolic solution for calculating $k$ from $k_2$, $G_2$ and maybe $P$ ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems unrelated  to cryptography.

Comment: The question is not necessarily clear. One possible symbolic solution is $[k] = P/G$. (i.e. $k$ is the discrete log of $P$ relative to base $G$ if we were writing this multiplicatively.) I'm assuming that's not the one you're looking for. I guess you mean one that can be efficiently evaluated? What is $n$? If $n$ is an unknown random number, then there's no information whatsoever in $j_2,k_2$. For any pair $j_2,k_2$ there exists an $n$ such that the equation holds.

Comment: If $j_2$ is another point then the second equation is still problematic since we cannot multiply points. I think you are still in the context of [ChainOfFools/CurveBall Attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83308/18298), that actually I wrote it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering the question with the equations as they stand in [Rev 18](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/83338/18). I'll assume $G$ and its [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $n$ are known (that's not stated).

> What is the symbolic solution for calculating $k$ from $k_2$, $G_2$ and maybe $P\,$?

If the point multiplications in the question are on a secure curve, and no relation is known between $G$ and $G_2$, then we can't find $k$ as asked. That would be solving a discrete logarithm problem. There is nothing in the question suggesting an insecure curve.

---

However, we can compute a $G_2$ so that $P$ is a valid private key for known public key $k_2$, and that could enable an attack if a target can be convinced that a certificate for public key $P$ intended for generator $G$ really is for generator $G_2$.

The idea is to choose $G_2=[i]\,P$ for some appropriate integer $i$, selected so that the desired $[k_2]\,G_2=P$ holds. That goes:

- Replace $G_2$ in $[k_2]\,G_2=P$ with its value in $G_2=[i]\,P$, we get $[k_2]\,([i]\,P)=P$
- Change that to $[k_2\,i]\,P=P$ (that follows from definition of point multiplication as repeated addition, and [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) of point addition: adding $i$ copies of $P$, then $k_2$ copies of the outcome, yields the same thing as adding $k_2\,i$ copies of $P$)
- It holds $[-1]\,P=-P$ (where the second $-$ is the opposite for point addition on the curve).
- We add the two equations and get $([k_2\,i]\,P)+([-1]\,P)=P+(-P)$ (where $+$ is point addition on the curve)
- We apply [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of scalar multiplication w.r.t. point addition, and that $P+(-P)=\infty$ by definition of the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for point addition, and get $([k_2\,i-1]\,P)=\infty$
- By definition of the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $n_P$ of point $P$ on the curve, that's equivalent to $k_2\,i-1\equiv0\pmod{n_P}$.
- Since $[k]\,G=P$ for some (unknown) $k$, $n_P$ much divide the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $n$ of point $G$ on the curve (in practice $n$ is a known prime number, thus $n_P=n\,$).
- It is thus enough to choose $i$ such that $k_2\,i-1\equiv0\pmod n$, that is $i\equiv{k_2}^{-1}\pmod n\,$.

Wrapping up: we compute $i={k_2}^{-1}\bmod n\,$, then compute $G_2=[i]\,P$ by point multiplication. Again, $n$ is the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of $G$ on the Elliptic Curve considered, and generally [given with the definition of the curve](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#page=7). Integer $i$ is the multiplicative inverse of $k_2$ modulo $n\,$, and can be computed using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures). In [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) and later, that can be computed as `i = pow(k2,-1,n)`.

---

Note: if we had the choice of $k_2$, we could more simply choose $k_2=1$ and $G_2=P\,$; or alternatively $k_2=(n-1)/2$ and $G_2=P+P\,$.

Comment: This is exactly the CurveBall, ycombinator has already a sage code that probably you already know. So, what is your actual problem? Can't you use the code?

Comment: @Donald The $k_2$ is `kprime` and a random element on the base field. then `Gprime = ZZ(kprimeinv) * Q ` (your $G_2$) is calcualted with this. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22059900

Comment: Kalalaka, read again please my answer, I need a k, not k_2 !!!